# Acync JS HTTP Request Advice Request

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a javascript library for a project im doing that makes rest calls based on params you feed it. This is the second day of the project and I'm looking for advice. If I set my request to be async it returns my request but i can't access the object value, if I set it to false in the call it returns an object.

I read the stack articles on async js request, and I can't seem to wrap my head around call backs and promises.

this works:
    request.open("DELETE", url, false);

this doesn't:
    request.open("DELETE", url, true);

```
(function(window){
    function defineCynergi(){
            var Cynergi = {};
            Cynergi.get = function(url){
                var request = makeHttpObject();
                request.open("GET", url, false);
                request.send(null);
                return JSON.parse(request.responseText);                
            }
            Cynergi.delete = function(url){
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("DELETE", url, false);
                request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/localhost.com:3000+json; version=1');
                request.send();
                deleteStatus = request.statusText;
                return deleteStatus;
            }

            Cynergi.insert = function(url, data){
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("POST", url, false);
                request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/localhost.com:3000+json; version=1');
                request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                sentStatus = request.statusText;
                return sentStatus;
            }

            Cynergi.update = function(url, data){
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("PATCH", url, false);
                request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/localhost:3000+json; version=1');
                request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                updateStatus = request.statusText;
                console.log(request);
                return updateStatus;
            }

            return Cynergi;
        }

    if(typeof(Cynergi) === 'undefined'){
        window.Cynergi = defineCynergi();
    }

})(window);

function makeHttpObject() {
  try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}

  throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', yourURI, true); // true = async
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange(function () {
    if(request.readyState === 4){
        /*ENTER CODE THAT SHOULD BE EXECUTED WHEN REQUEST IS DONE 
        (OPTIONAL)*/

        switch(request.status) {
             case 200: //DO STUFF
             case 404: //DO OTHER STUFF
        }
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', yourURI, true);
request.addEventListener('load', function () {
    //CODE THAT SHOULD BE EXECUTED WHEN SUCCES.
});
request.addEventListener('error', function () {
    //CODE THAT SHOULD BE EXECUTED WHEN ERROR RESPONE.
});
request.send();
```